# Having a strange issue with the mac calendar app

Tags: macos, calendar

Sometimes when I create a calendar event and begin adding in alerts for it, the event will randomly auto-delete all of the alerts. Here is a screen recording of this happening.

https://vimeo.com/user107142004/review/382625926/e9c52eacd3

Let me know if you know why this is occurring, and if you have experienced it too.

EDIT: I go to add alerts for the event in calendar (I like to have many: 30 min before, 2 hours before, 2 days before, 5 days before, etc). Sometimes the alerts I create simply disappear, and it goes back to the default. There have even been other times where I add alerts, and they show up on the event, but when I close the app and re-open, the alerts that were previously there are now gone.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add the steps you're taking?  Just referring to a video doesn't allow the search feature to capture the issue properly.

Comment: What version of the System are you running and what computer do you have.  I'm running High Sierra on an iMac and I always use  2 or more alerts. They stay there when I reopen them.

Comment: I'm running macOS Catalina Version 10.15.3. I have a 2019 MacBook Pro.